# about setting up the set_terminate function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, exception

i am using a visual studio c++ compiler,& during my study on exception handling,i came across a number of features that can't be supported by visual c++ compiler,
like controlling the exceptions that can be thrown out of a function.
also i was unable to modify the functioning of **terminate()** using **set_terminate()** .
is it a specification too for visual c++ to modify **terminate()**?...& if so,then  can anyone explain that why microsoft is creating these specifications in its compilers?...:-x

Comment: What's the question? You don't get why `set_terminate()` is there or what?

Comment: @sharptooth: i was trying to set the terminate() using set_terminate(),but it fails to do so ...i was asking about the reason..

Comment: Okay, what exactly you do and what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: @sharptooth:read the answer given by the c programmer below,i have done the same thing,but the set_terminate is unable to modify the working of terminate(),can you explain the answer given by the cprogrammer below,more clearly..

Comment: Well, he overrides the `terminate()` handler and then throws an unhandled exception and that leads to his terminate handler being called. That should work for everyone. We do similar things and it works for us.

Comment: yo,but it is not called in my case, & at the end of c programmer's answer,he conveys the same thing,but i am unable to grab the the reason behind it,@sharptooth:

Comment: The reason is that Visual Studio runs your program in a debug environment. This is necessary because you want features like breakpoints, view data values, access violations and more.

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean you were unable to modify terminate

have you tried something like this ?

```
// set_terminate example
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void myterminate () {
  cerr << "terminate handler called\n";
  abort();  // forces abnormal termination
}

int main (void) {
  set_terminate (myterminate);
  throw 0;  // unhandled exception: calls terminate handler
  return 0;
}
```

Don't try to run from VS. Compile and exec from command line.

Comment: It will work in the IDE, just not in debug mode. (I.E. Select Debug menu -> Start without debugging. Or press Ctrl+F5)

Comment: I use VS2008 and it does not work for me in Release mode either.
Is there some other possible reason (like setting in Debug->Exceptions) ??
At least it works outside VS2008...